# Getting Error in Eclipse "Cannot instantiate the type Scanner"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to learn java but While dealing with the Scanner type I ran into the error, "Cannot instantiate the type Scanner".
here is my code

```
import com.sun.java_cup.internal.runtime.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 2;

        for (int i = 1; i != 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(a + " X " + i + " = " + a * 1);
        }
        int i = 1;
        while (i != 10) {
            System.out.printf("%d X %d = %d\n", a + 10, i, (a + 10) * i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're importing `Scanner` from the wrong package. Change the import to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using the auto complete <Ctrl+Shift+o> and it imported the previous package.

Comment: @nabeel: I suspect it actually offered you both options, and *you picked* the one shown in your post.

Comment: I know we get to pick when Eclipse imports new packages, but this issue has happened to me multiple times and I don't ever remember picking `com.sun.java_cup.internal.runtime.Scanner`.